# Как собрать все возможные формы слова в список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pymorphy2, морфология

Хочу собрать все возможные формы слова в один список с помощью библиотеки `pymorphy2`. Атрибут `lexeme` выводит большое количество ненужной информации и я не знаю как вывести все формы слова, которые она дает.

Как это реализовать?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
p = morph.parse('погода')[0]
print(p.lexeme)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь атрибутом [.lexeme](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html#inflection):

```
p = morph.parse('погода')[0]
```

---

```
In [35]: [(x.word, x.tag.case, x.tag) for x in p.lexeme]
Out[35]:
[('погода', 'nomn', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,nomn')),
 ('погоды', 'gent', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,gent')),
 ('погоде', 'datv', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,datv')),
 ('погоду', 'accs', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,accs')),
 ('погодой', 'ablt', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,ablt')),
 ('погодою', 'ablt', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,ablt,V-oy')),
 ('погоде', 'loct', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,loct')),
 ('погоды', 'nomn', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,nomn')),
 ('погод', 'gent', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,gent')),
 ('погодам', 'datv', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,datv')),
 ('погоды', 'accs', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,accs')),
 ('погодами', 'ablt', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,ablt')),
 ('погодах', 'loct', OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn plur,loct'))]
```